# Number of keys typed

Tags: python, pyhook

I have some problems in returning the number of keys typed on the keyboard.

I finished the part when he can detect every key typed but I need the number of total keys typed.

This is my code written in python:

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print ('Key:', event.Key)
    print ('---')

    return True

def events():
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
    hm.UnHookKeyboard()

events()
```

Comment: Do you mean "typed" or perhaps "recorded"?

Comment: typed 
when you type anything I need to return the number of keys that you clicked

Comment: Updating a global from within the hook would seem completely trivial compared to the code you already have written. If you didn't write this yourself, perhaps try a quick Python tutorial before asking for help?